# Vertical spring

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to reproduce the figure below.
[image]

I have encountered issues when drawing the vertical right spring, connecting the wall to the bottom block. The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{
   decorations.markings,
   decorations.pathmorphing,
   calc,
   patterns,
   positioning
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0pt,thick}]
\tikzstyle{spring}=[thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm,post length=0.3cm,segment length=6}]
\tikzstyle{damper}=[thick,decoration={markings,
  mark connection node=dmp,
  mark=at position 0.5 with
  {
    \node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
    \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$);
  }
}, decorate]
\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.75cm,minimum height=0.3cm]

\node [ground, rotate=180, minimum width=12cm,yshift=-5cm] (wall) {};
\node [minimum width=12cm, minimum height=0.5cm] (m1) {$m_1$};

\draw (wall.north east) -- (wall.north west);
 
\draw [line width=0.8pt]  ($(wall.north west)!0.1!(wall.north east)$) -- ++(0,-1cm)coordinate (z);
\draw [spring]   (z) -- ++(0,-3cm)coordinate (u);
\draw [line width=0.8pt]   (u) -- ($(m1.north east)!0.1!(m1.north east)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How the bottom endpoint of the spring could be moved to the left, as shown in the output?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TikZ, `(a |- b)` (resp. `(a -| -b)`) is the point whose abscissa is that of `(a)` and ordinate that of `(b)` (resp. the point which has the ordinate of `(a)` and the abscissa of `(b)`).

Don't use `\tikzstyle`: it is obsolete. You can replace it with `pgfkeys` key assignments such as `spring/.style={...}`, as shown below. And please make your example closer to a minimal one next time, by removing unused things as I did here (for one, the `damper` style isn't used in your example).

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.pathmorphing, patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={draw, outer sep=0pt, thick},
  spring/.style={thick, decorate,
                 decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm, post length=0.3cm,
                             segment length=6}},
  ground/.style={fill, pattern=north east lines, draw=none,
                 minimum width=0.75cm, minimum height=0.3cm}]

\node[minimum width=12cm, minimum height=0.5cm] (m1) {$m_1$};
\node at (0,5cm) [ground, minimum width=12cm] (wall) {};

\draw (wall.south east) -- (wall.south west);

\draw[line width=0.8pt]
  ($(wall.south west)!0.9!(wall.south east)$) -- ++(0,-1cm) coordinate (z);
\draw[spring] (z) -- ++(0,-3cm) coordinate (u);
\draw[line width=0.8pt]   (u) -- (u |- m1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an equivalent code without `calc`, that finds point `($(wall.south west)!0.9!(wall.south east)$)` using a different technique. Note these two lines:

```latex
\draw (wall.south west) -- (wall.south east) coordinate[pos=0.9] (p);
\draw[line width=0.8pt] (p) -- ++(0,-1cm) coordinate (z);
```

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={draw, outer sep=0pt, thick},
  spring/.style={thick, decorate,
                 decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm, post length=0.3cm,
                             segment length=6}},
  ground/.style={fill, pattern=north east lines, draw=none,
                 minimum width=0.75cm, minimum height=0.3cm}]

\node[minimum width=12cm, minimum height=0.5cm] (m1) {$m_1$};
\node at (0,5cm) [ground, minimum width=12cm] (wall) {};

\draw (wall.south west) -- (wall.south east) coordinate[pos=0.9] (p);
\draw[line width=0.8pt] (p) -- ++(0,-1cm) coordinate (z);
\draw[spring] (z) -- ++(0,-3cm) coordinate (u);
\draw[line width=0.8pt]   (u) -- (u |- m1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Example with the `damper` style

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.markings, decorations.pathmorphing, patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={draw, outer sep=0pt, thick},
  spring/.style={thick, decorate,
                 decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.3cm, post length=0.3cm,
                             segment length=6}},
  ground/.style={fill, pattern=north east lines, draw=none,
                 minimum width=0.75cm, minimum height=0.3cm},
  damper/.style={
    thick, decoration={
      markings,
      mark connection node=dmp,
      mark=at position 0.5 with
        {
          \node (dmp) [thick, inner sep=0pt, transform shape, rotate=-90,
                       minimum width=15pt, minimum height=3pt, draw=none] {};
          \draw [thick] ([xshift=2pt] dmp.north east) -- (dmp.south east) --
                        (dmp.south west) -- ([xshift=2pt] dmp.north west);
          \draw [thick] ([yshift=-5pt] dmp.north) -- ++(0,10pt);
        },
    },
    decorate,
  }]

\node[minimum width=12cm, minimum height=0.5cm] (m1) {$m_1$};
\node at (0,5cm) [ground, minimum width=12cm] (wall) {};

\draw (wall.south west) -- (wall.south east) coordinate[pos=0.9] (p);
\draw[line width=0.8pt] (p) -- ++(0,-1cm) coordinate (z);
\draw[spring] (z) -- ++(0,-3cm) coordinate (u);
\draw[line width=0.8pt]   (u) -- (u |- m1.north);

\coordinate (q) at ($(wall.south west)!0.7!(wall.south east)$);
\draw[damper] (q) -- (q |- m1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was not familiarized with the syntax '(a |- b)'. I have kept the other elements such as 'damper', because I am gonna use them for reproducing the model shown in the first figure.

Comment: Glad to help. I understand for the `damper` style, but it's better to include in your examples here *only* what is needed. This makes them shorter, much easier to read, so that more people will read them and benefit from the question & answers (the more code there is, the more likely people will just give up reading). Another related thing that can be useful is `intersection cs`. There is an example in the [Ti*k*Z & PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: There is also a small problem... Why the code does not works in \documentclass{article} ?

Comment: You probably forgot `\usepackage{tikz}` (don't use the `tikz` option of `\documentclass` if you use the `article` class, but do insert `\usepackage{tikz}` before `\usetikzlibrary{...}`).

Comment: Ok, it works wfine with \usepackage{tikz}. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to define the `damper/.style` using the style from the OP, but when adding `\draw[line width=0.8pt] ($(wall.south west)!0.2!(wall.south east)$) -- ++(0,-1cm) coordinate (z1);
\draw[damper] (z1) -- ++(0,-3cm) coordinate (u1);
\draw[line width=0.8pt]   (u1) -- (u1 |- m1.north);`, the following error occurs: `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decoration/\pgfkeyscurrent
name ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.`

Comment: The damper is defined as: `damper/.style={thick,decorate,
                 decoration={markings,
                 mark connection node=dmp,
                 mark=at position 0.5 with
        {\node (dmp) [thick,inner sep=0pt,transform shape,rotate=-90,minimum width=15pt,minimum height=3pt,draw=none] {};
        \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north east)+(2pt,0)$) -- (dmp.south east) -- (dmp.south west) -- ($(dmp.north west)+(2pt,0)$);
        \draw [thick] ($(dmp.north)+(0,-5pt)$) -- ($(dmp.north)+(0,5pt)$)}}}`

Comment: You just need to add `\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.markings}` for this `damper` style. I've added a full example (and modified it slightly: my `damper` style doesn't require the `calc` library, although the way I place it in the sample figure does require `calc`, as it provides a straightforward way to achieve the desired placement).

Comment: Ok, I understand. I have added initially in the preamble `calc` and `decorations.markings`, but I removed them with `\tikzstyle`. Thank so so very much!